# What client-side browser languages are widely available?

Tags: java, javascript, flash, browser, client-side

I've read a bit on client-side browser languages and tried a few out but I'm not convinced I know of all the options. To make it clear, I'm looking for something that can be processed either through the browser or otherwise on the clients computer with minimal need for additional installations/configurations.

At the moment I know of JavaScript, Java, and Flash ( I'm aware this isn't actually a language, but seems pertinent to mention it still as an option). If at all possible it seems like avoiding Flash would be best, but it's still a consideration. I know there are various flavors of JS and Java but I don't really know of any that make the end-product that different than just the raw language. Java and JavaScript both seem relatively slow when it comes down to more complex and weighty apps, though performance is always improving as our browsers and libraries get better.

All this said, is there anything available or about to be available that will do things better?

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do? Usually the requirements drives the technology.

Comment: I'm not necessarily trying to build anything specific so much as figure out what the boundaries are. Mainly, making things seem more application-like within the browser would be a goal. This would include simple things we take for granted normally like dynamically updating the screen (without refreshing) and being able to "grab" or "move" things that show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is the only *native* browser language that’s widely supported. Flash isn’t native, but it’s the most widely-supported plug-in.

Nothing else yet seems to be installed widely enough to be worth considering in general, although obviously you should always try to figure out what the actual/intended audience of your specific project has installed.

JavaScript performance has come on leaps and bounds in the latest versions of all browsers as it’s become more widely used.

As far as interface programming goes, the only thing JavaScript has built in is the DOM interface, which lets you programmatically control the HTML page that the JavaScript is running on. The DOM interface is pretty raw and basic, so there are lots of frameworks that try to make it more palatable (like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)), and frameworks that seek to provide libraries of desktop-like UI controls (e.g. [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/), [Cappucino](http://cappuccino.org/)).

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is the main language for client-side browser development that interacts with the elements on the page, does ajax requests (update screen without a full page refresh), etc. Depending on your specific requirements, I would recommend JavaScript, as its most likely the tool that will accomplish your needs.

Java is NOT a client-side browser language, Java is a programming language, you can write apps in Java and embed them in a website, that is called a Java Applet. This will require that all users have a JRE installed on their machine for your applet to work.

Java has nothing to do with Javascript -- they share some similar syntax, and thats about it.

Flash is a browser plugin, if you want to write a flash application, ActionScript is the language it uses. It still requires that anyone going to view your application have the Flash plugin installed.

Comment: Apologies about the misleading description of Java, I wasn't meaning that it was somehow magically in the browser but more that it is an option for web-app development.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 is the future.

Currently many features are achieved with JavaScript, but these are being wrapped in libraries (e.g. the "polyfill" library [Modernizer](http://www.modernizr.com/) and even in other languages, e.g. Java with GWT.  This is an area in a greater state of flux than most.

Comment: HTML 5 provides some additional APIs to JavaScript, but it isn't a programming language in its own right.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot unity.

Unity is an up-coming client-side application development platform. It does require installing just like flash but it's a lot more powerful then flash and seems to be picking up popularity.

Unity has a lot more inbuild framework rather then doing it in HTML5+JavaScript. I would say these are your two main options. For an example of javascript & html5 in action look at [`cloud9ide`](http://www.cloud9ide.org/)

One of the big advantages of unity is the 3D engines.

Java applets are so 1998 and are not an option.

Comment: Unity seems like it may be a pretty bulky package just like Flash. Are there any examples currently running that show off the capabilities of their new client-side platform?